# How can I use python to iterate through multiple csv files and if a value is the same, update another value?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to iterate through a few .csv files, and if a value is the same, add up the related entries. If a value is not the same, add that as a new row.

My current code is:

```
import pandas
s1011 = pandas.read_csv('goals/1011.csv', sep=',', usecols=(1,3,5))
s1011.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
print s1011

s1112 = pandas.read_csv('goals/1112.csv', sep=',', usecols=(1,3,5))
s1112.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
print s1112

s1213 = pandas.read_csv('goals/1213.csv', sep=',', usecols=(1,3,5))
s1213.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
print s1213
```

Currently this doesn't do much I know. It prints out 3 headings, Team, For & Against. It the prints out 20 football teams, how many goals they've scored, and how many conceded. I've tried using *merge* in python but it isn't suitable as it just makes one big table.

What I'm trying to do is open the multiple csv files, iterate through the list, if the *Team* is the same, add together goals for and goals against from each file. If *Team* has not been entered before, add a new row with new entries.

Is this possible using python?

Edit:

It currently prints

> Team
>   For 
>   Against
>
> Man Utd
>   86
>   43
>
> Man City
>   83
>   45
>
> Chelsea
>   89
>   39

etc for 20 teams. So I want to update the For and Against entries by adding up the number of goals for each team over a number of seasons. Since it won't be the same 20 teams each season, I want to add a new row of entries if a team hasn't been in the league before.

Comment: it is usually better if you provide examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the following csv's:

> ## df1
>
> Team For Against
>
> Man Utd 86 43
>
> Man City 83 45
>
> Chelsea 89 39
>
> ## df2
>
> Team For Against
>
> Man Utd 88 45
>
> Man City 85 47
>
> ICantNameATeam 91 41

You can first stack them using pandas.concat:

```
df_concat = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

which would give you:

> ## df_concat
>
> Team For Against
>
> Man Utd 86 43
>
> Man City 83 45
>
> Chelsea 89 39
>
> Man Utd 88 45
>
> Man City 85 47
>
> ICantNameATeam 91 41

Then you can use dataframe.groupby to take the sum:

```
df_sum = df_concat.groupby('Team').sum().reset_index()
```

This will group the dataframe according to unique team names and take the sum of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

1. Use Pandas to append the file's identifying number to the For & Against column in each dataframe (i.e. For-1011, For-1112, For-1213).
2. Use a full outer join on 'Team' to bring in all rows into a new dataframe.
3. Sum the columns as you'd like: `df[For-total] = df[For-1011] + df[For-1112] + df[For-1213]`